# Get reference to method function by name?

Tags: javascript

I want to store a function, internal to the function-object its within, in an object member, but I need to get access to it via name.  The code below makes it easier to understand...

// MyClassThing.js:

```
var MyClassThing = (function() {
    var _ref = {obj: undefined, fnc: undefined};

    function setup(domObject, refName) {
        _ref.obj = domObject;
        _ref.fnc = this['func_' + refName]; // <<-- This does not work!!
    }

    function doThing() {
        if(_ref.func)
            _ref.fnc();
    }

    function func_foo() {
        console.log('Foo!');
    }

    return { 
        setup: setup,
        doThing: doThing
    };
})();
```

// index.html

```
<script>
MyClassThing.setup($('#fooObj'), 'foo');
MyClassThing.doThing();
</script>
```

What do I do to get `_ref.fnc = ????` to work properly?

Answer (score 4):

You will have to use helper object to put methods as its properties. Then you will be able to refer to them by variable name:

```
var MyClassThing = (function () {

    var _ref = { obj: undefined, fnc: undefined },
        methods = {};

    function setup(domObject, refName) {
        _ref.obj = domObject;
        _ref.fnc = methods['func_' + refName];
    }

    function doThing () {
        if (_ref.fnc) _ref.fnc();
    }

    methods.func_foo = function () {
        console.log('Foo!');
    };

    return {
        setup: setup,
        doThing: doThing
    };
})();
```

You can't use `this` because it points to the object returned from IIFE, however your methods of interest are not properties of this object.

Comment: Aaah.  This is much better than ``eval``!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your code:

```
var MyClassThing = (function() {
    var _ref = {obj: undefined, fnc: undefined};

    function setup(domObject, refName) {
        _ref.obj = domObject;
        _ref.fnc = this['func_' + refName]; // <<-- This does not work!!
    }

    function doThing() {
        if(_ref.fnc)
            _ref.fnc();
    }

    function func_foo() {
        console.log('Foo!');
    }

    return { 
        setup: setup,
        doThing: doThing
    };
})();
```

In your `doThing` function, you are checking for the existency of a `_ref.func` instead of `_ref.fnc`

To achieve what you want to do, you need to understand that the functions you are declaring using the "function" are not linked to the class. There's no notion of "private member function" in javascript. If you want to bind a function to a class, you need to declare it like this (there are other ways, i'm just showing you one of them) :

```
MyClassThing.prototype.func_foo = function () {

}
```

The best thing to do, in your case, would be to set `_ref.fnc` to `func_foo` directly. If you want to keep the `this` context, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Thanks for noticing the typo.  That was dummy code I wrote for this example, mimicking my actual class.  :)